# Is there some kind of http validator?

Tags: json, node.js, http, postman

I am writing a web service in node, and testing it with Postman.  I spent a long timing looking for an error.  When I finally found it, it turned out to be a simple error formatting the response body, which is json.

1. If I leave off the final brace in the response body, Postman waits for two minutes, and then reports that it received everything, just fine.
2. If I leave off the closing quote in the last value in the json, Postman says the server didn't respond, perhaps I should check my security certificates.

I would much rather Postman said "Hey, Buddy, you left off a quote!"

If there some validation service I can talk to?  Or a plugin in Postman?

Comment: 1) it should not be possible to produce badly formatted JSON from such a service as you should never be producing it in any way other than with a JSON serializaer 2) you are asking for an HTTP validator when what you really want is a JSON validator

Answer (score 1):

Here there are some `validation` javascript libraries, you can use:

- [Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) provides a declarative way of validating javascript objects.
- [Express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) acts as an express.js middleware for node-validator.

Meanwhile, Postman got [API testing and Collection Runner](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/pre_request_scripts) that can help you through this; which you can write some `pre-request script` as well as `test script` for each request.

Also, they got **Newman** which is a command-line collection runner. It allows you to effortlessly run and test a Postman collection directly from the command-line. It is built with extensibility in mind so that you can easily integrate it with your continuous integration servers and build systems.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Paw worked (https://paw.cloud/).  And so far I haven't paid for it.

Where Postman said "check your security certificates," Paw said "we were expecting 376 bytes but you only sent us 312."

Cuts down my time solving the problem a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for this.  It is *very* good at identifying (with an error message that pops up) problems and bad implementations of the HTTP protocol.  Browse the web with it running, and within a few minutes you'll undoubtedly hit a poorly implemented server.

Postman won't be able to handle these cases since it's insulated from poor behavior by the browser's framework.

That's not your problem though.

> When I finally found it, it turned out to be a simple error formatting the response body, which is json.

That has absolutely nothing to do with HTTP.  HTTP doesn't know or care what your request/response bodies are.

The problem you face is that your API endpoint could be returning whatever it wants.  You need a custom solution to your problem, as there is no standard API server in this case.

Most folks will run unit tests that hit common endpoints of your service to ensure they're alive and well.

I should also point out that it should be all but impossible for you to break the JSON response if you're doing it correctly.  Sounds like you're serializing JSON manually... never do that, we have JSON serializers for this purpose.  Send in an object and let it worry about building the JSON output for you.  Otherwise, you'll waste a lot of time on problems like these.